# amazon s3 files storage

Tags: 7, cdn

We want to move all files to amazon s3 storage and I'm wondering if it is enough to move sites/default/files to a new storage.

I know there are modules which offer Amazon S3 support, but I would like to try a low level solution by mounting the new storage as the files directory and let the OS do the job.

Has anyone tried this before or should I just use [AmazonS3](https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3) or [Storage API](https://www.drupal.org/project/storage_api) modules? Thanks